# What is the timeout period for links in Civimail? Can it be extended?

Tags: civimail, drupal, tracked-links, 4.6.12

We send out a newsletter in Civimail, with links to our main website which is a different domain. We are using 'track click throughs' so the link, when clicked, goes via Civi first.  However, the links seem to be expiring fast - I sent a test last night and the links worked fine when I received the email.  But 10 hours later clicking a link just takes me into Civi, and not to the main website.  What is the default timeout and can it be changed?  We are on 4.6.12 and this is a Drupal site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes the checksum lifespan is configurable at this path civicrm/admin/setting/misc?reset=1 which you get to via Admin > System Settings > Misc

Changing the duration will only affect future checksums. It will not affect ones that have already been set out.

Comment: Thanks - this is set to 7 days, which is not what's happening.  I have changed it to 8 days & will test again

Comment: can you clarify '7 hours is not happening' - are you getting longer or shorter - are you certain it is correctly formed etc, ie does it work at all? can't see any reason the 7 days default would not be functioning

Comment: I sent an email out & the links expired overnight. Following your advice, I updated the checksum lifespan to 8 days.  An email I sent yesterday still has the links active, so looking good. So I'm wondering why I originally got the problem?

Comment: no idea unless something came along and wiped the table that holds the data (scratching head as can't recall where it is stored)

Comment: After saving the checksum lifespan and sending out a test email on 23/3 the links are still active on 26/3, so not sure what happened previously.